# MFC SDI and Dialog Boxes

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to create an application that has 5 dialog type windows in an SDI format. I need the dialog tabs so that the user can click on the different dialog window tab. Furthermore, I can not have any two dialog boxes visible at any one time.

Using the project wizard, I chose an SDI application and created 5 dialog boxes. I used InitDialog to maximize each Window.

Unfortunately, only the active dialog window shows. I can't see the other four windows in a tab-type style.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can use CPropertySheet. Or SDI with CFormView, and Tab control inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show more than one dialog at a time, use CDialog::Create to create a non-modal Dialog.

As you are talking from "window tab" look at CPropertySheet and CPropertyPage. Also CPropertySheet can be created non modal with CPropertySheet::Create.